# Printing with Ruby in Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, watir

hi i have a question about using watir
i am very new to ruby so i may ask stupid questions
my question is how do i print a webpage with watir/ruby?
is there a way to print the current webpage that i am viewing, if so can you provide some example code?

thanks for viewing!
hervey

Answer (score 0):

i think would you need to access the window.print() function in javascript or bind that in a function on an event handle of a button , link , image

Comment: is there anyway to interact with something like this? > http://i51.tinypic.com/2ziaafn.jpg, the box pop-up is not shown in firebug

Answer (score 0):

Although this would not be a true print you could use the [screen_capture method](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir/1.7.1/Watir/ScreenCapture) to save a bitmap of the current screen which you could print out later.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the AutoIt gem   it can click buttons up at the windows level, which would allow you to print.

As to the question you asked in the comment of the other proposed answer, dealing with the popup box, see this:  http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups